# Можно ли добавить элементы управления в скрипт JQuery Interactive 3D?

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d

Хочу на своем сайте использовать библиотеку [JQuery Interactive 3D](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/interactive_3d.html). Мне бы хотелось добавить элементы управления в виде стрелочек. Можно ли сделать это в этом скрипте и как? Может быть есть другие подобные скрипты, которые позволят мне добавить такие стрелочки?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ссылка на скрипт http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/interactive_3d.html